# How to pass xml file as parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, database

I am facing a interesting issue. I have to pass a html file as parameter to a method and that file is in data base.

Text of file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:13px;border:1px solid #d3d3d3">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
               <tr>
                  <td width="201">
                    <img src="cid:elogo.jpg" width="200" height="70" />
                  </td>
                  <td width="367">
                   <span style='float:right;color:#706b66;padding:30px 15px 0 22px;font-size:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>
                    <strong>#PASSWORD_TITLE#</strong>
                  </span>
                 </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding:0 20px 0px 37px;">
               <tr>
                  <td>Dear #USER_NAME#,</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>#BODY_TEXT#</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

The parameter is which i am passing is:-

```
javaScript:clickKey('${recConfig.configId}','${recConfig.key}','${recConfig.value}','${recConfig.description}','${recConfig.categoryName}')"
```

All data from database is coming and i am using Spring MVC and Hibernate. One of the third value of parameter is a html file.

When i am passing file this way then i is not working properly. When i inspected this issue, I observed that due to html file 4 and 5 parameter are showing on page and third parameter is not coming as parameter.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you submit the content with method "POST" or "GET"? If you use "GET", try "POST". When it shows the same error, please create a clickable jsfiddle example.

Comment: I have tried this thing but this is not working.

Comment: <c:forEach var="recConfig" items="${propManger.listPropUsers}" varStatus="index3">
         <tr>
           <td class="category"> ${recConfig.categoryName}</td>     
           <td class="key">  <a href="#" onclick="javaScript:clickKey('${recConfig.configId}','${recConfig.key}','${recConfig.value}','${recConfig.description}','${recConfig.categoryName}')">${recConfig.key}</a></td> 
                <%--  <td class="value">${recConfig.value}</td> 
         --%>   <td class="description">${recConfig.description}</td> 
         </tr>
        </c:forEach>

Comment: listConfigValues =  service.getPropertyManageDetails();
   propertyManagerDto.setListPropUsers(listConfigValues);
   mv.addObject("propManger", propertyManagerDto);

Comment: Have you noticed, that we needed the source code of your javascript method 'clickKay()'?

Comment: Code for Prop click is  <a href="#" onclick="javaScript:clickKey('${recConfig.configId}','${recConfig.key}','${recConfig.value}','${recConfig.description}','${recConfig.categoryName}')">${recConfig.key}</a>

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem sometimes back and it should be due to the quotes in the HTML content.
One solution could be while loading encode the html content and then pass to the clickKey() function and when you have to render it you should decode it with decodeURI() function in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of my problem.

I used htmlEscape method of Spring to convert by html file into escaped form

```
HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(String to convert)
```

This gives me converted String and i passed this to required place.

Answer (score 0):

we can go with a hidden parameter.

set data in hidden parameter after htmlEscaping and get the data in javascript

html:

<input type='hidden' id='keyName' value='<%=strKeyName%>'/>

js:

- keyName = $("#keyName").val();

> Blockquote